# Select only last value using group by at mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have one table with data about attendance into some events. I have in the table the data of the attendance everytime the user sends new attendance, the information is like this:

```
mysql> SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member FROM view_event_attendance WHERE id_event = 782;
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id_branch_channel | id_member | attendance | timestamp  | id_member |
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|              1326 |    131327 |        459 | 1363208604 |    131327 |
|              1326 |    131327 |        123 | 1363208504 |    131327 |
|              1326 |    131327 |          1 | 1363208459 |    131327 |
|              1326 |     93086 |          0 |       NULL |     93086 |
|              1326 |     93087 |          0 |       NULL |     93087 |
|              1326 |     93088 |          0 |       NULL |     93088 |
|              1326 |     93093 |          0 |       NULL |     93093 |
|              1326 |     99113 |          0 |       NULL |     99113 |
|              1326 |     99135 |          0 |       NULL |     99135 |
|              1326 |     99199 |          0 |       NULL |     99199 |
|              1326 |     99200 |          0 |       NULL |     99200 |
|              1326 |    131324 |          0 |       NULL |    131324 |
|              1326 |     85850 |          0 |       NULL |     85850 |
|              1326 |     93085 |          0 |       NULL |     93085 |
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(This is actually a view, for that reason some of the fields are null).

I can groupby id_member so I get only one row for every member (that is, only the last attendance the user sent). However, when I do it, I received the first attendance the user sent, not the last one.

```
mysql> SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member FROM view_event_attendance WHERE id_event = 782 GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id_branch_channel | id_member | attendance | timestamp  | id_member |
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|              1326 |    131327 |          1 | 1363208459 |    131327 |
|              1326 |     93086 |          0 |       NULL |     93086 |
|              1326 |    131324 |          0 |       NULL |    131324 |
|              1326 |     93087 |          0 |       NULL |     93087 |
|              1326 |     93088 |          0 |       NULL |     93088 |
|              1326 |     93093 |          0 |       NULL |     93093 |
|              1326 |     99113 |          0 |       NULL |     99113 |
|              1326 |     99135 |          0 |       NULL |     99135 |
|              1326 |     85850 |          0 |       NULL |     85850 |
|              1326 |     99199 |          0 |       NULL |     99199 |
|              1326 |     93085 |          0 |       NULL |     93085 |
|              1326 |     99200 |          0 |       NULL |     99200 |
+-------------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I already tried to add ORDER BY clausules, but they are not working at all... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: this is the script that creates the table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_event_attendance 
    AS
        SELECT 
            tbl_event.id_event,
            tbl_member_event.id_member,
            tbl_event.id_branch_channel,
            tbl_member_event_attendance.id_member_event_attendance,
            IF(ISNULL(tbl_member_event_attendance.attendance), 0, tbl_member_event_attendance.attendance) AS attendance,
            tbl_member_event_attendance.timestamp
        FROM 
            tbl_event
            INNER JOIN 
                tbl_member_event ON tbl_member_event.id_event = tbl_event.id_event
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    tbl_member_event_attendance ON tbl_member_event_attendance.id_member_event = tbl_member_event.id_member_event
        ORDER BY 
            tbl_member_event_attendance.timestamp DESC;
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks a lot MichaelBenjamin, but the problem when using subqueries is the size of the view:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member 
    -> FROM (select * from view_event_attendance order by timestamp desc) as whatever
    -> WHERE id_event = 782 
    -> GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                       | type   | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                                            | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                  | ALL    | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                                           | 16755 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event            | index  | id_event        | id_event        | 8       | NULL                                           | 16346 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_event                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_event        |     1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event_attendance | ref    | id_event_member | id_event_member | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_member_event |     1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

As you can see there are a lot of rows in my table, so for that reason I don't want to use subqueries...

**EDIT 3:**

But adding WHERE to the subquery it looks better...

```
mysql> DESCRIBE SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member 
    -> FROM (select * from view_event_attendance where id_event = 782 order by timestamp desc) as whatever
    -> WHERE id_event = 782 
    -> GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                       | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                                            | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                  | ALL   | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                                           |   14 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_event                   | const | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       |                                                |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event            | ref   | id_event        | id_event        | 4       |                                                |   12 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event_attendance | ref   | id_event_member | id_event_member | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_member_event |    1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If I can not find anything else not using subqueries, I think I'll choose this as the answer...

**Edit 4**

After seeing the comments in the answer, I've decided to select another as the answer. Here is the DESCRIBE for both queries, and I think it is obvious what is the best solution:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE SELECT 
    ->   id_branch_channel,
    ->   id_member, 
    ->   attendance, 
    ->   timestamp,
    ->   id_member
    -> FROM view_event_attendance AS t1
    -> WHERE id_event = 782
    -> AND timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    ->                  FROM view_event_attendance AS t2 
    ->                  WHERE t1.id_member = t2.id_member 
    ->                    AND t1.id_event = t2.id_event 
    ->                  GROUP BY id_event, id_member)
    -> OR timestamp IS NULL
    -> GROUP BY id_event, id_member;
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                       | type   | possible_keys      | key                      | key_len | ref                                            | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tbl_event                   | index  | PRIMARY            | id_member_branch_channel | 4       | NULL                                           |  208 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tbl_member_event            | ref    | id_event           | id_event                 | 4       | video_staging.tbl_event.id_event               |   64 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tbl_member_event_attendance | ref    | id_event_member    | id_event_member          | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_member_event |    1 | Using where; Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl_event                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY                  | 4       | func                                           |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl_member_event            | eq_ref | id_event,id_member | id_event                 | 8       | video_staging.tbl_event.id_event,func          |    1 | Using where; Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl_member_event_attendance | ref    | id_event_member    | id_event_member          | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_member_event |    1 | Using where; Using index                                  |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> DESCRIBE SELECT *
    -> FROM (SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_event 
    ->       FROM view_event_attendance 
    ->       WHERE id_event = 782 
    ->       ORDER BY timestamp desc
    ->      ) as whatever
    -> GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                       | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                                            | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                  | ALL   | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                                           |   14 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_event                   | const | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       |                                                |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event            | ref   | id_event        | id_event        | 4       |                                                |   12 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_member_event_attendance | ref   | id_event_member | id_event_member | 4       | video_staging.tbl_member_event.id_member_event |    1 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I believe you can do what you're trying for by using max() or a similar function on one of the grouped columns.  i don't have a similar table set up right now to test with.

Comment: You could check my answer for a solution that works without subqueries or joins.

Comment: I'd be interested to see actual times; the describe difference is what I'd expect and doesn't lead me to think one is clearly better.  And it would be nice if you gave my answer a try too :)

Comment: @ysth I wish to, but I do not know how to make it... Can you please clarify me? Maybe you can do it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a6e7/1

Comment: ok: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af2a1/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a simple group by id_member, but select:

```
substring(max(concat(from_unixtime(timestamp),attendance)) from 20) as attendance
```

This attaches attendance to the timestamp for each row in a group, in order to be able to select the desired timestamp/attendance with max() and then extract just the attendance.

What `concat()` returns is 19 characters of formatted timestamp (YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS) with the attendance appended starting at character 20; the `substring(... from 20)` gets just the attendance from the (stringwise) maximum one for the group.  You can remove the group by and just

```
select concat(from_unixtime(timestamp),attendance), timestamp, attendance
```

to get a better idea of how it uses max to get the right attendance.

Comment: Can You Update your answer with the full query? I'll add the explain later. Thanks for your help. Also, could you explain why the `from 20`?

Comment: I'd rather just provide the expression to select, since no other changes are necessary to your original query; having to wade through the full query will make it harder for someone else to find and use this idea with their query.

Comment: very clever, and dramatically faster than the subquery-and-join approach

Comment: I love this solution, it's the faster ever for this problem. You have to pay attention and consider length of your discriminating fields but with right and left it's simple. Great!

Answer (score 4):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(%requiredfield%), ',', count(*)),',',-1)
```

This will get the last value of the 'required field' from any group_concat, if unsorted it will be the last value in the table by default.

Could use group_concat_ws to account for possible null fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member 
FROM (select * from view_event_attendance order by timestamp desc) as whatever
WHERE id_event = 782 
GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
```

**EDIT:** This may yield better performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id_branch_channel, id_member, attendance, timestamp, id_member 
      FROM view_event_attendance 
      WHERE id_event = 782 
      ORDER BY timestamp desc
     ) as whatever
GROUP BY id_event,id_member;
```

As long as the result-set can fit into the Innodb_buffer_pool, you will not see a significant performance drop.

Comment: Selecting only what you need from the inner query and moving the where into it may give you better performance.

Answer (score 3):

The following works, but unfortunately it has a subquery again and won't perform much better than the other solutions posted here.

```
SELECT 
  id_branch_channel,
  id_member, 
  attendance, 
  timestamp,
  id_member
FROM view_event_attendance AS t1
WHERE id_event = 782
AND timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                 FROM view_event_attendance AS t2 
                 WHERE t1.id_member = t2.id_member 
                   AND t1.id_event = t2.id_event 
                 GROUP BY id_event, id_member)
OR timestamp IS NULL
GROUP BY id_event, id_member;
```

Comment: I'll test It tomorrow and let You know if It fits my needs. If does then this will be the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This actually works and I prefer this solution. I think it cost less to the database, and I really need to improve in this regard. Thanks a lot to everyone for your help. I already knew how to do it with subqueries, but I don't like it so much, so for this reason I'm chosing this as the solution to my problem.

Comment: can you explain how it works?  (because I think you are completely misunderstanding what `having max(timestamp)` does)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option (untested):

```
SELECT v.id_branch_channel, v.id_member, v.attendance, v.timestamp, v.id_member 
FROM view_event_attendance v
    JOIN (
        SELECT id_event, id_member, MAX(attendance) maxattendance
        FROM view_event_attendance 
        GROUP BY id_event, id_member ) m ON 
            v.id_event = m.id_event AND
            v.id_member = m.id_member AND
            v.attendance = m.maxattendance
WHERE v.id_event = 782 
GROUP BY v.id_member;
```

The concept is to get the `MAX()` of timestamp and use that field to `JOIN` on your view.  You might not need all the fields -- really depends on your table structure.  But this should get you going in the correct direction.

Comment: It works great! But the only problem is that only returns one row... I want all the 12 rows in the example I gave but the first one, instead of being the row with attendance 1, the row with attendance 459. Thanks for your help. I'll check your code and see if I can modfiy it to my benefit (although I wish not to do subqueries...)

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita -- The only other option I can think of without using subqueries is to use user-defined variables in your query.  However, I don't think you'd get much of a performance increase with that -- in fact, it might be slower.  I didn't completely understand your question -- replace MAX(timestamp) with MAX(attendance) and you should get the 459 instead (obviously update your JOIN as well)...

Comment: @sgeddes: I believe he wants the attendance from the row with the greatest timestamp, even if the timestamp is lower.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a window function and a subquery, if you add an entry to your select list as `row_number() over (partition by id_member order by timestamp desc)` this will resolve to a number ordering the rows by timestamp (with 1 being the oldest) grouped in each id_member group (run it if this doesn't make sense, it will be clear). You can then select from this as a subquery where the extra column = 1 which will only select the rows with the highest timestamp within each group.

Comment: Thanks for your help... but I really have no idea what do you mean... sorry. Can you please give me an example with the query I added? Thanks a lot for your willing to help me! :)

Comment: window functions require mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.2