# Improve performance on greatest n with multiple join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, filesort

So I was playing some sql indexes and see if I can improve my sql performance. I'm using the data from employees table https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db, and dump the employees.sql.

After looking up the structure a bit, my question was how do I get 10 people with the highest salary and what are the title. I come up with some solution.

```sql
select e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.gender, salaries.salary, titles.title from employees e
inner join ( 
    select s.emp_no, s.salary from salaries as s  
    left outer join salaries as s2
    on s.emp_no = s2.emp_no 
    and s.salary < s2.salary
    where s2.emp_no is null
) salaries on salaries.emp_no = e.emp_no 
inner join (
    select t.emp_no, t.title from titles as t  
    left outer join titles as t2
    on t.emp_no = t2.emp_no 
    and t.to_date < t2.to_date 
    where t2.emp_no is null
) titles on titles.emp_no = e.emp_no
order by salaries.salary desc
limit 10;
```

Basicly since the `employees` have one-to-many relationship for titles and salaries I must group the `salaries` and `titles` by its latest greatest value, for `salaries` it will be `salary` column and for `titles` it will be the `to_date` column.

The SQL works perfect, but it was so slow ~ even after creating some index.

```sql
create index salary_emp_no_index on salaries (salary, emp_no);
create unique index emp_first_last_name_index on employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, gender);
create index titles_emp_title on titles (emp_no, title)
```

What I am doing wrong here? Is there still a room for improvement?

Edit (added sqlfiddle)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72111d/1

Comment: your question title and tags say greatest n per group, but your question text is just about greatest n, _not_ per group.  which is what you actually mean to be asking?

Comment: you are more likely to get an answer if you include the create table and inserts of sample data for the specific tables relevant to your question in the question itself (as text, not images)

Comment: I list the optimal techniques here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: Ah yes sorry I mean greatest N. @ysth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

First, to get the greatest salary for each emp_no and limit to 10, you don't need a subquery or join at all, you can simply do (untested):

```
select emp_no, max(salary) max_salary
from salaries
group by emp_no
order by max_salary desc
limit 10
```

Second, you only need the titles for those (up to) 10 employees, so use your max salary query as a cte or subquery and only look for titles for those employees, which should be much faster.  Additionally, you can avoid the self-join on titles using the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422121/17389.