# GROUP BY: can values from the SELECT clause be used to establish functional dependence?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand why a column that I expect to hold nondetermistic values after a `GROUP BY` actually contains the correct values, despite the fact that the `GROUP BY` columns are not sufficient to identify a row.

Please consider the following query, which retrieves the oldest price for each brand-seller-product combination:

```
SELECT
    price, brand, seller, product, min(date) AS date
FROM
    priceHistory
GROUP BY
    brand, seller, product;
```

At first, I was expecting this query to return a nondeterministic value for `price`. Instead of that, I invariably get the expected `price` value for the returned `date`.

So, I looked for an explanation in MySQL's documentation about `GROUP BY`. There, I found out about functional dependences, and learned that MySQL is able to determine the correct values for the `SELECT` columns that are not mentionned in the `GROUP BY` clause, when the `GROUP BY` column (or set of columns) is a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY`.

Now, I do have a `UNIQUE KEY` declared in my table:

```
UNIQUE KEY `uniquePrice` (`brand`,`seller`,`product`,`date`),
```

This `UNIQUE KEY` has one column (`date`) that is not included in the `GROUP BY` columns. However, the `min(date) AS date` expression in the `SELECT` clause does return a unique `date` value.

So, my guess is that MySQL combines the `brand`, `seller`, and `product` columns from the `GROUP BY` clause on one hand, and the unique `date` value from the `SELECT` clause on the other hand, to "reconstruct" the `UNIQUE KEY`. At which point it is able to establish functional dependence, and identify the row from which the `price` value should be retrieved.

Is my assumption correct?

If so, could you show me how I could have verified it on my own?

If not, do you have an alternative explanation?

Comment: You could also just be getting lucky. The question I have is why are you using an incompletely group by, a feature that was removed from mysql all the way back in version 5.7 and has not been allowed in any other RDBMS under the sun for decades?

Comment: I suspect it happens accidentally as a result of the way it uses the index to get `min(date)` -- since it has that index element in memory, it uses it to fetch a row from the group in the main table, so you get the corresponding price. But this is just an optimization, there's no guarantee it will work.

Comment: @JNevill I cannot answer your question, as I was not the author of this code. I am indeed considering a rewrite if no one confirms my assumption. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, that might explain it. Thanks for the input. I wouldn't have thought about that.

Comment: some ways to do it in a guaranteed to work fashion are shown in various answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15421616/17389

Comment: What is the value of the `sql_mode` option in the session that runs this query? (it might be different from the global value) You can check with `SELECT @@sql_mode;`. If it does not include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, then MySQL permits queries that fail to comply with the single-value rule, and it'll arbitrarily return the value of `price` as the first value it reads as it scans the index. As others have commented, you might be getting the price from the same row that has the minimum date, but it's by coincidence.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is not even a valid `GROUP BY`.  It won't even run in any other dbms.

Comment: @ysth Wow! Thank you very much! That'll definitely help.

Comment: @BillKarwin `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is indeed disabled. Coincidence was my first thought, but I just couldn't find a way to make it not happen. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: @Eric Yes, as I said to JNevil, I'm not the author of this code, and I was just trying to understand why it _seemed_ to be working. I'll definitely rewrite it. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: A way to consider is that there will be one output row with `brand, seller, product`, if for those three columns of the same value, there are multiple rows, each with a different `price`, what `price` should appear in the result set. For `date`, you've explicitly said `min`, but that doesn't mean the `min` price is selected.

Comment: *do you have an alternative explanation?* Let's think how does this query is executed. MySQL uses an index for to find each row in each `brand, seller, product` group which have minimal `date` value. Imagine that an index record for some definite group value is found. Now the server must access the table body and retrieve the column which is not included into this index. Of course it uses "current" index record. It extracts row's primary key value and reads this row, extracting needed `price` value. Of course you receive the `price` value which matches minimal `date` value.

Comment: @danblack I think you misunderstood. The query is not supposed to select the `min(price)` for the group, but the `price` value that is associated to the `min(date)` (i.e. the oldest price).

Comment: @Akina Wouldn't your explanation imply that the query should also work when substituting `max` for `min`? Because it doesn't.

Comment: @ysth Thanks again! Your link was a big help.

Comment: *Because it doesn't.* Searching for a group and searching MAX/MIN in the group are two separate searches. Build ``UNIQUE KEY `uniquePrice` (`brand`,`seller`,`product`,`date` DESC)``, and it will work for MIN but not for MAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After processing all the comments to my question and doing a little more investigation, I would say that values from the SELECT clause are *not* used to establish functional dependence. At the very least, I can say for sure that it's not what's happening in my case.

My assumption about functional dependence being established was incorrect. It can be demonstrated very easily by substituting `max` for `min` in the query. The result rows then contain the most recent `date` values, as expected, but still have the oldest `price` for each brand-seller-product group.

It turns out that my query was indeed returning the expected `price`s by coincidence.

For the sake of completeness, and as explained by @ysth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422121), a nice, simple way to guarantee that the `price` and `date` values are retrieved from the same row would be:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(MIN(CONCAT(date, price)) FROM 20) AS price, brand, seller, product, MIN(date) AS date
FROM
    priceHistory
GROUP BY
    brand, seller, product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Window function partitioned what you have GROUP BY to be allows the elements of `price` and `date` to match. By ordering these in `date ASC` means the first row of each windows is the one you want.

```
WITH summary AS
  (SELECT p.price,
          p.brand,
          p.seller,
          p.product,
          p.`date` AS date ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.brand, p.seller, p.product
                                             ORDER BY p.`date` ASC) AS rank
   FROM priceHistory p)
SELECT *
FROM summary
WHERE rank = 1
```

ref: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)